# mp3 song upload code in php is not working well

Tags: php, mp3

i have a web site, here i need to implement a php function to upload  a song (mp3 ) and need to play that song. I have done  a code. see my code

```
if(trim($_FILES['frmFile']['name'])!=""){ 
        if (($_FILES["frmFile"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg" || $ext=="mp3" ||  $ext=="MP3")&& ($_FILES["frmFile"]["size"] < 2000000))
            { 
            if ($_FILES["frmFile"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                $error="Error In Uploading";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $orgFileNmae=$_FILES['frmFile']['name'];
                $uniqname = rand().$fileName.".".$ext;
                 $uploadfile=$uploaddir.$uniqname;

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['frmFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                }

            }
            }else{
                $error="Invalid file";

            }

            }
```

I have  downloaded an mp3 song from online, and tried to upload the file, but it's showing

> error in Uploading, i have print the file attributes, then i got `$_FILES["frmFile"]["error"] =1`

Then i have simply play the downloaded code in vLc and other player it's working well. Then why don't this file not uploading correctly..

I have printed the uploaded files array then i got the result

```
Array ( [name] => blind_willie.mp3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )
```

Does anyone know ?

Any one have  a good code to upload an mp3 song

Thanks in advance

Comment: no size is not big. i ahve downloaded  a file with smallest size

Answer (score 1):

As per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), upload error `1` means the file is too large and exceeds the preset PHP maximum allowed upload file size.

Your code's logic flow is also backwards - the very FIRST thing you should check is the `['error']` parameter, BEFORE you do anything else. You may not get a valid filename with a failed (or non-existent) upload, but you still proceed as if everything went fine. As well, you are trusting the user to not provide a fake filename and using that user-provided filename as the basis of your upload security. It is trivial to forge that filename, allowing them to upload anything they want, simply by renaming `nastyvirus.exe` to `goodsong.mp3`.

```
if ($_FILES['frmFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['frmFile']['error']);
}
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if($finfo->file($_FILES['frmFile']['tmp_name']) != 'audio/mpeg') {
    die("Invalid file type uploaded");
}
etc...
```

Comment: +1 for using finfo() to check the mime type. You shouldn't trust the ['type'] in $_FILES as it can be spoofed by the client for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following values to increase file upload size

```
file_uploadsile_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size
```

Cheers